# PHP: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Tags: php, html, email

Intento crear un formulario de contacto que se envíen sus datos a un correo de gmail. Para esto utilizo la biblioteca `PHPMailer`, pero primero estoy intentando que el correo llegue con un texto simple, o sea sin pasarle ninguna variable. El problema es que da un error (al parecer de sintaxis) como si no estuviera reconociendo los parámetros de la clase `phpMailer`.

Este es el error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\CU\sendbymail.php on line 11

Este es el código php:

```
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
require_once('class.smtp.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail­->IsSMTP();
$mail-­>SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail-­>SMTPAuth = true;
$mail-­>SMTPSecure = "ssl";
//indico el servidor de Gmail para SMTP
$mail-­>Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
//indico el puerto que usa Gmail
$mail-­>Port = 465;
//indico un usuario / clave de un usuario de gmail
$mail­->Username = "usuarioX";
$mail-­>Password = "passwordX";
$mail­->SetFrom('correo@gmail.com', 'Nombre');
$mail­->AddReplyTo("correo@gmail.com","Nombre");
$mail­->Subject = "Asunto del correo";
$mail-­>MsgHTML("Hola, este es el cuerpo del mensaje!");
//indico destinatario
$address = "correoDestino@gmail.com";
$mail­->AddAddress($address, "Mi nombre");
if(!$mail­->Send()) {
echo "Error al enviar: " . $mail-­>ErrorInfo;
} 
else {
echo "Mensaje enviado!";
}
```

Entonces, la línea 11 del código a la que se refiere el error es esta:

```
$mail­->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

Leo una y otra vez y no veo ningún error en esa línea ni en ninguna otra de ese fichero. Sin embargo cuando la quito o comento entonces el error me da en la próxima donde se encuentra el siguiente operador `=`, o sea, en esta:

```
$mail­->SMTPAuth = true;
```

Y así sucesivamente con las demás líneas. Sin embargo realizo cualquier operación simple utilizando dicho operador (`=`) y que no requiera el uso de la clase `PHPMailer`, y, en este caso, sí lo reconoce y se me ejecuta la operación. Por lo que sospecho que el error tiene que ver algo con que no se esta cargando bien la clase `phpMailer` o no puede acceder a sus métodos, pero no logro ver donde está el error.

Comment: Adriana, te falta la asignación "->" ...

Comment: Cierto, pero fue un error al copiar para acá. En el original lo tengo bien. Gracias @Elenasys. Ya edité la pregunta y lo arreglé

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hice el experimento de copiar y pegar tu código a Notepad++ y me aparece así:

```
$mail--­>IsSMTP();
$mail­-->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

**Fíjate en los dobles guiones**. Por otro lado, si copio/pego el código que publicó @Jorgesys, los guiones aparecen correctamente:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
```

Hice la prueba usando http://phpcodechecker.com/. Copié/pegué tu código y me dio el mismo error que comentas. Escribí directamente el código y no dio problema.

Entonces, si el código no lo escribiste tú sino que lo copiaste y pegaste desde otro sitio, es probable que te esté inyectando un carácter que se ve "igual" al guión, pero que al no serlo, dispara el error.

Comment: Oh!!, hice la misma prueba que tu y me sale igual con doble guiones, es extraño porque al probarlo me aparecía bien, bueno al parecer este que planteas es el problema, porque sí es cierto que ese código lo copie de otro lado. Lo probare y cuando compruebe que me funciona haciéndolo manualmente te marco el aceptado, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Hace poco tiempo realicé lo mismo y me funcioné , te lo mando tal cual:

```
 <!--ENVIO DE EMAIL-->  
        <?php
        require '../correo/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

     //Variables recibidas:
     $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

    //Permite modo debug para ver mensajes de las cosas que van ocurriendo
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

    //Hacer autenticación SMTP:
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";//CON SSL NO ME FUNCIONO

    //Indico el servidor de Gmail para SMTP:
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 

    //Indico el puerto que usa Gmail:
    $mail->Port = 587;

    //Indico email de emisor:
    $mail->Username = "xxxx@gmail.com";

    //Indico nombre de ususario de emisor:
    $mail->FromName = "Anonimo";

    //Indico contraseña de emisor:
    $mail->Password  = "xxxxxxxx";

     //Cuerpo del mensaje por defecto.
     $body=$mensaje;        
     $mail->Body = $body;

    //Email al que puede responderte el usuario: '**Esto lo ve el       usuario**': 
    $mail->addReplyTo($email,$nombre);

    //Asunto del mensaje:
   $mail->Subject = 'Contacto: Pagina_Web';

   //Cuerpo del mensaje: 'html/txt'.
   $mail->msgHTML($mensaje);
   $mail->AltBody = $mensaje;

   //Indico destinatario:
    $address = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
    $mail->addAddress($address, "Correo");

   //Envio el email:
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
             //error en mensaje:'saco mensaje'
             echo "<p>Error al enviar mensaje.</p>"; /*. $mail->ErrorInfo;*/
             echo('<a href="javascript:history.back(1)">Volver Atrás</a>');
   } else {
             //Mensaje enviado:'saco mensaje'
             echo "<p>Mensaje enviado!!.</p>";
             echo('<a href="javascript:history.back(1)">Volver Atrás</a>');
    }
 ?>
```

Fuera parte de configurar en mi caso el archivo de configuración 'php.ini' ya que uso Xampp y poner lo siguiente en la zona de [mail function]:

```
[mail function]
sendmail_from = xxxxxx@gmail.com
sendmail_path ="\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Yo el problema que tuve era el sendmail_path que pone solo unix y de eso nada, también windows lo necesita. A mi esto me ha funcionado.

Por otro lado en tu correo gmail debes de permitir correos 'no seguros' por decirlo así.

espero te funcione.

Comment: Probé tu solución y al menos, ya no me sale el error de php, pero ahora la página se me queda cargando "para siempre" y no sale de ahi, además de que no envia el correo. Debo tener algo mal en la configuracion del php.ini. Yo también uso windows y mi servidor es wamp. También tengo el sendmail.exe. Como resolvistes tu lo del sendmail_path para windows?

Comment: lo del send mail path lo configuro en el php.ini , ami me dio problemas porque pone solo para unix en un comentario que trae, y lo unico que hice es a puntar a la carpeta que hay dentro de xampp >sendmail> y sendmail.exe lo que viene siendo esto:        sendmail_path ="\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

Answer (score 0):

Esto es correcto ya que habilitas modo "DEBUG":

```
$mail­>SMTPDebug = 2;
```

El problema es la sintaxis que es incorrecta, debe ser con `->`

```
$mail-­>IsSMTP();
$mail­->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail­->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail­->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
//indico el servidor de Gmail para SMTP
$mail-­>Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
//indico el puerto que usa Gmail
$mail­->Port = 465;
//indico un usuario / clave de un usuario de gmail
$mail­->Username = "usuarioX";
$mail­->Password = "passwordX";
$mail­->SetFrom('correo@gmail.com', 'Nombre');
$mail­->AddReplyTo("correo@gmail.com","Nombre");
$mail­->Subject = "Asunto del correo";
$mail­->MsgHTML("Hola, este es el cuerpo del mensaje!");
    ...
    ...
```

En los métodos no causa problema (aparentemente), pero cuando lee las propiedades y tratas de asignar un valor como en `$mail­>SMTPDebug = 2;` marca el error.

Comment: Si la sintaxis la tenía mal pero fue al copiar el código para acá, en el proyecto lo tenía bien, asi que este no es el error. Gracias de todas formas.